std::integer_sequence in a lambda before C++20
I have started using this type of construction, which depends on C++20's explicit template parameters for lambdas:
template<typename... Ts>
struct Foo
{
  std::tuple<Ts...> bars;

  auto get_labels(const std::array<std::size_t,sizeof...(Ts)>& indices) const
  {
    // construct tuple from bar labels
    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::make_tuple(std::get<Is>(bars).get_label(indices[Is])...);
      }(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{});
  }
};

Compiler Explorer example
How can I do this in C++17 or C++14 (without explicit template parameters for lambdas)?

Using a specific language standard is never a requirement on its own. However if you can move the code using this template to  seperate static libs compiled with C++20 you may leave the rest of the code in C++14/17.  (Linking between different versions should be ok due to ABI compatiblity as long as you don't expose C++20 things on the "interface")

@PepijnKramer unfortunately this is in a header-only library. (That's what I mean by requirement -- make C++20 a requirement for consumers/users of the library.)

GCC/Clang supports template lambdas even in C++14, which means you can directly switch your code to C++14.

So it's important to recognize what part you actually need. When you write this:
// construct tuple from bar labels
return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<Is>(bars).get_label(indices[Is])...);
}(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{});

What you actually need is Is.... Or, more generally, what you actually need is a pack of constant values. In the above example, you are accepting a parameter of index_sequence<Is...> - that's one parameter, whose type has the pack of constant values in it.
But a different way to do it would be to accept N different parameters, where the first parameter is of type integral_constant<size_t, 0> and the second parameter is of type integral_constant<size_t, 1>, and so forth. If you could produce those arguments, then the lambda part becomes
[&](auto... Is){
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<Is>(bars).get_label(indices[Is])...);
}

Note that the body is identical, I just changed what the parameter(s) looks like. And this is now a valid C++14 lambda.
So the rest of the problem is producing the function template with<N>(f), which calls f(integral_constant<size_t, 0>{}, integral_constant<size_t, 1>{},..., integral_constant<size_t, N-1>{}) which allows you to call:
return with<sizeof...(Ts)>([&](auto... Is){
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<Is>(bars).get_label(indices[Is])...);
})

And writing with in C++14 is straightforward. It's really just the same index_sequence trick, with an extra indirection (cause you need to then change the one index_sequence into the N integral_constants). Arguably, the result looks better too - it's less busy. I prefer this in C++20 anyway.

just to be sure that I have not missed something; each Is of the auto...Is will be an instance of std::integral_constant<size_t,X> for different X. Then the Is in get<Is> will be converted in an integer because std::integral_constant has a conversion operator that is constexpr.  Is that so ?

@edrezen Yep, exactly right.

Ok thanks. You definitely convinced me to use a scheme like with for iterating an integer range in contexts such as providing an argument to std::get.

One possible way is to "place" the sequence directly in the class template:
template <typename Seq, typename... Ts> struct FooImpl;

template <std::size_t... Is, typename... Ts>
struct FooImpl<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...>
{
  static_assert(sizeof...(Is) == sizeof...(Ts));
  std::tuple<Ts...> bars;

  auto get_labels(const std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)>& indices) const
  {
    // construct tuple from bar labels
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<Is>(bars).get_label(indices[Is])...);
  }
};

template <typename... Ts>
using Foo = FooImpl<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>, Ts...>;


@Barry's answer is probably best for the question I actually asked, but I think this answer is what I want. This lets me avoid a bunch of immediately-invoked lambdas in my class. And I already have the implementation in an impl:: namespace, so this doesn't even change my interface.

A straightforward approach is to make the lambda a member function:
template<typename... Ts>
struct Foo
{
  std::tuple<Ts...> bars;

  template <std::size_t... Is>
  auto get_labels_(
    const std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)>& indices,
    std::index_sequence<Is...>
  ) const
  {
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<Is>(bars).get_label(indices[Is])...);
  }

  auto get_labels(const std::array<std::size_t,sizeof...(Ts)>& indices) const
  {
    // construct tuple from bar labels
    return get_labels_(indices, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{});
  }
};

Not sure if it qualifies as relatively elegant, though.

Hmm, I suppose that could work. It would effectively double the length of my class, so it's not super elegant; at least I could hide the implementation function as private, I guess.

A way to skip the lack of template lambda is to have a template method that returns the lambda:
template<typename... Ts>
struct Foo
{
    std::tuple<Ts...> bars;

    template <std::size_t... Is> 
    auto make_lambda (std::index_sequence<Is...>, const std::array<std::size_t,sizeof...(Ts)>& indices) const
    {
        return [&] (std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
        {
            return std::make_tuple(std::get<Is>(bars).get_label(indices[Is])...);
        };
    }
 
    auto get_labels (const std::array<std::size_t,sizeof...(Ts)>& indices) const
    {
        auto seq = std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{};
        return make_lambda (seq, indices) (seq);
    }
};

Demo
This should work starting with c++14.
Note: this is somehow similar to the previous answer that I have not seen before posting. Maybe it underlines a little bit more the underlying intent, ie. making a lambda template but is even less friendly.
So, c++20 is a good move if you can use it in your context.
